# Oil change: which is the best option?

Tags: engine, oil-change

I am a new driver and need to change oil. I have following options. Which one should I select?

My car:
Toyota Camry 1994 LE, 4 cyl, 127000 miles.

NTB: $19.99
It includes following services:

1. Tire Rotation
2. TPMS Reset where applicable
3. Battery Check
4. Belts and Hoses Check
5. Brakes Check
6. Fluids Top Off

Jiffy Lube: $30
It includes the following services:

1. Brake fluid level (in transparent reservoirs)
2. Serpentine belts
3. Wiper blades
4. Antifreeze/coolant reservoir levels
5. Engine air filtration system
6. Exterior lights
7. Chassis (lubricate when applicable)
8. Tire pressure
9. Transmission/transaxle fluid
10. Differential fluid
11. Transfer case fluid
12. Power steering fluid
13. Windshield washer fluid
14. Battery water (excluding sealed batteries)
15. Exterior windows
16. Vacuum interior floors

Firestone $21
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTB or Firestone... or...
D.I.Y. for price of motor oil - Priceless.

Cost of 4 quarts of oil is approx. $15-$25, depending on quality, plus the filter means the rest of the time they spend on checking all the other fluids and wear parts is their way to find and upsell more work. Have them show you all the things they check and what they are looking for, and then you can do that yourself in the future.